# scaling multiple columns in lists using map, map2, mutate_at, summarise_at

Tags: r

I am having problems with the `scaled_assessment` data I am trying to create.

I have some time series data I split up into `analysis` and `assessment`. I want to scale the `analysis` data and use these scaled `means` and `sd`'s to apply to the `assessment` data. I add comments to the code below.

I run into problems tackling the `mutate_at` function. I want to apply the scale function which takes in the `mean` and `sd` from the `analysis` data and apply it to the `assessment` data. - For all columns in the `assessment` data.

Data / code:

```
    library(rsample)
set.seed(1131)
# I create some random data
ex_data <- data.frame(row = 1:20, some_cat_var = paste("cat"), some_var = rnorm(20), some_other_var = rnorm(20))
ex_data

# I create the analysis and assessment splits - the analysis data has 10 observations the assess has 1
rolled_ex_data <- rolling_origin(ex_data,
                                 initial = 10,
                                 assess = 1, 
                                 cumulative = FALSE,
                                 skip = 0)

# My scaling function to apply to the analysis data
Scale_Me <- function(x){
  (x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}

# This I believe "works" I collect the mean and sd from the 3rd and 4th column of the data for each split
scale_values <- map(rolled_ex_data$splits, ~ analysis(.x) %>% 
                      as_tibble(., .name_repair = "universal") %>% 
                      summarise_at(.vars = 3:ncol(.), .funs = c(mean = "mean", sd = "sd")))

# I then apply the scale function to the analysis data (to columns 3 and 4) for each split
scaled_analysis <- map(rolled_ex_data$splits, ~ analysis(.x) %>% 
                         as_tibble(., .name_repair = "universal") %>% 
                         mutate_at(.vars = 3:ncol(.), .funs = c(Scale_Me = "scale")))

# My problem is here with the mutate_at function
scaled_assessment <- map2(rolled_ex_data$splits, scale_values, ~ assessment(.x) %>% 
                            as_tibble(., .name_repair = "universal") %>% 
                            mutate_at(.vars = 3:ncol(.), .funs = c(scaled_col = (.vars - .y$mean) / .y$sd)))
```

## EDIT:

Okay. I have managed to get it working for the two variables using `mutate`.

```
scaled_assessment <- map2(rolled_ex_data$splits, scale_values, ~ assessment(.x) %>% 
                            #as_tibble(.x, .name_repair = "universal") %>% 
                            mutate(
                              some_var_scaled = (some_var - .y$some_var_mean) / .y$some_var_sd,
                              some_other_var_scaled = (some_other_var - .y$some_other_var_mean) / .y$some_other_var_sd
                              )
                          )
```

This gets me a list of 10:

```
scaled_assessment[[1]]
scaled_assessment[[2]]
scaled_assessment[[3]]

> scaled_assessment[[1]]
  row some_cat_var  some_var some_other_var some_var_scaled some_other_var_scaled
1  11          cat -1.350214      -0.569947       -1.603747            -0.2836588
> scaled_assessment[[1]]
  row some_cat_var  some_var some_other_var some_var_scaled some_other_var_scaled
1  11          cat -1.350214      -0.569947       -1.603747            -0.2836588
> scaled_assessment[[2]]
  row some_cat_var some_var some_other_var some_var_scaled some_other_var_scaled
1  12          cat 2.242594      -1.195205        3.038992            -0.7670828
> scaled_assessment[[3]]
  row some_cat_var some_var some_other_var some_var_scaled some_other_var_scaled
1  13          cat 1.781132      0.9764677        1.593273              1.194117
```

I would like to know how to do it using `mutate_at` because I do not know the number of time series columns I have to scale. Here I use 2 columns `some_var` and `some_other_var` but I could have 3 or 4 columns which is why I tried to use `.vars = 3:ncol(.)`.

Comment: you are doing `.y$mean) / .y$sd` but `scale_values` have no such column. Can you also show your expected output ?

Comment: My expected output is to apply the `Scale_Me` function to columns `3:4` - so I will create 2 new columns which uses the mean and sd from the `scaled_values` table.

Comment: Not sure if I have understood the question correctly (as it still lacks expected output) but I think you should take a step back. Why to calculate `mean` and `sd` values differently ? Why don't you apply `Scale_Me` function directly to `rolled_ex_data$splits` ? `map(rolled_ex_data$splits, ~ analysis(.x) %>% 
      mutate_at(3:ncol(.), Scale_Me))`

Comment: I will work on an expected output as I see you are also trying to help me on a different (yet very similar) question I asked. I want to use the `mean` and `sd` from the different dataset since I am dealing with time series and I will not know the `assessment` data ahead of time. I want to use the mean and sd computed on the `analysis` data to be applied to the `assessment` data.

Comment: Okay, I managed to get the code working for the two variables which I show in the edit. Hopefully it is a little more clear.